# how can i get trend topic tweet with Twitter Api

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, applet

I have Twitter Developer Account.
How can i get trend topic tweet with Twitter Api ?

Console output:

```
"message" : "Bad Authentication data.",
"code" : 215
```

My Code:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/available.json")//

        Alamofire.request(url!).responseData { response in
            debugPrint(response.result.value)

            TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn{
                (session, error) in
                if session != nil {
                    print("succsess")
                } else {
                    print("Fail")
                }
            }

            let data = JSON(response.result.value)
            print("########\(data)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: All Twitter API calls in 1.1 require authentication with OAuth now. So you will need to lookup OAuth with Twitter before making this call.

Comment: how can i call OAuth ?

Comment: By doing some simple research like [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+twitter+oauth) perhaps?

Comment: I searched but could not find a solution.